# How do I list the files in subfolders and output this list to a local file?

Tags: linux, bash, find, output, ls

I am using `find` and `ls` to list the mp3 files contained in subfolders. In each subfolder I want to output the list of the files it contains to a local file (stored in this subfolder).

I tried this command :

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp3 -execdir basename {} >> playlist.m3u \;
```

but the file `playlist.m3u` it writes in is stored in the root directory `.` and not the subdirectory of the found mp3 file.

Is there a way to write to a file stored in the subdirectory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command, this will help you :

```
   find -type d -exec bash -c 'cd $1; find  -maxdepth 1  -not -name "." -name \*.mp3 -printf "%f," | awk "{print substr(\$0,0,length(\$0)-1)}"  > playlist.m3u' bash "{}" \;
```

This will separate list of files with commas, please change this accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ! I adapted your command to : `find -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1"; find -maxdepth 1 -name \*.mp3 -printf "%f\n" > playlist.m3u' bash "{}" \;`